# Map array from another api endpoint and pass through prop of React child component

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, react-props

I need to pass responses from two APIs, i.e. hobbies and person API, to my child component. So I am able to `map()` the child component and show the data in a list.

The response from person api:

```
{[
0: {id: 01, name: {…}, familyName: {…}, phone: 0 …}
1: {id: 02, name: {…}, familyName: {…}, phone: 0 …}
2: {id: 03, name: {…}, familyName: {…}, phone: 0 …}
3: {id: 04, name: {…}, familyName: {…}, phone: 0 …}
4: {id: 05, name: {…}, familyName: {…}, phone: 0 …}
5: {id: 06, name: {…}, familyName: {…}, phone: 0 …}
6: {id: 07, name: {…}, familyName: {…}, phone: 0 …} 
]
}
```

The response from hobbies api:

```
{ data: {
  name: "Test name"
  hobbies: (2) [{…}, {…}]
  userId: "test"
  _id: "4767647478"
 }
}
```

The component:

```
const PersonList = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [persons, setPersons] = useState<Person[]>([]);
  const [hobbies, setHobbies] = useState<Hobbies[]>([]);

  const urls = [
    "https://person-api",
    "https://hobbies-api",
  ];

  const getData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const [result1, result2] = await Promise.all(
      urls.map((url) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json()))
    );

    setLoading(false);
    setPersons(result1);
    setHobbies(result2);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {persons.map((person) => {
          return (
            <PersonCard
              key={person.id}
              name={person.name}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PersonList;
```

The above code works fine and renders a list of names of the persons. But how do I `map()` and pass the `hobbies` (from different api response) with a prop e.g. hobbies through my child component,like below?

```
 <PersonCard
  key={person.id}
  name={person.name}
  hobbies={hobby.name}
 />
```

Comment: can you share a sample response of both apis. that would be required to map them somehow and pass to child component

Comment: @RaviChaudhary I added the api response structure to my question.

Comment: The response you have shared doesn't help much as I can't figure out how the hobbies and person are connected. We need some id minimum to connect the two. What I can tell you is that you can use `find` method on hobby array to figure out the hobbies of the person using the id.